# Creating a Bash File With a Looped Menu (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop, menu

*Edited to update status

I am trying to make a bash file that will allow you to select an option, output the answer and then loop back to the menu selection. As of right now, the code I have is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo off
echo "........................................."
echo "Select the process you would like to run."
echo.
echo "1 - Free Disk Space Available"
echo "2 - List Directories"
echo "3 - Show Running Processes"
echo "4 - TCP Connection"
echo "5 - Network Interfaces"
echo "6 - List Directories"
echo "7 - Show Computer Hostname"
echo "8 - Routing Table"
echo "9 - Computer Uptime"
echo "10 - Available Block Devices"
echo "11 - Mount Device"
echo "........................................."

echo -n "Input desired function number and press ENTER: "
read selection
while [ {selection} ]
do
    if [ $selection == 1 ]; then echo df -h
        break
    elif [ $selection == 2 ]; then echo ls -l /home
        break
    elif [ $selection == 3 ]; then echo ps -A
        break
    elif [ $selection == 4 ]; then echo netstat -a
        break
    elif [ $selection == 5 ]; then echo ifconfig
        break
    elif [ $selection == 6 ]; then echo $PATH
        break
    elif [ $selection == 7 ]; then echo hostname
        break
    elif [ $selection == 8 ]; then echo route
        break
    elif [ $selection == 9 ]; then echo uptime
        break
    elif [ $selection == 10 ]; then echo blkid
        break
    elif [ $selection == 11 ]; then echo mount
        break
    else
        echo "Please enter a valid option"
    fi
done
```

The output I get is an error that infinitely loops with

> [: 2: unexpected operator

If anyone could help me out or guide me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That edit changed the question completely. It's ok to update question, but consider adding a comment to the answer that helped you, that you ran into another problem.

Comment: note that `echo off` prints the word "off". bash is not batch.

Answer (score 1):

For menus, use the `select` command. Here, I'm using `bash` to store the options into an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ".............................................................................."
echo "Select the process you would like to run by pressing the corresponding number."

choices=(
    "Free Disk Space Available"
    "List Directories"
    "Show Running Processes"
    "TCP Connection"
    "Network Interfaces"
    "List Directories"
    "Show Computer Hostname"
    "Routing Table"
    "Computer Uptime"
    "Available Block Devices"
    "Mount Device"
)

PS3="Input desired function number and press ENTER: "
select selection in "${choices[@]}"
do
    case "$selection" in 
        "${choices[0]}" ) echo df -h ;;
        "${choices[1]}" ) echo ls -l /home ;;
        "${choices[2]}" ) echo ps -A ;;
        "${choices[3]}" ) echo netstat -a ;;
        "${choices[4]}" ) echo ifconfig ;;
        "${choices[5]}" ) echo $PATH ;;
        "${choices[6]}" ) echo hostname ;;
        "${choices[7]}" ) echo route ;;
        "${choices[8]}" ) echo uptime ;;
        "${choices[9]}" ) echo blkid ;;
        "${choices[10]}" ) echo mount ;;
    esac
done
```

If you want to break out of the menu, you would do

```
        "${choices[10]}" ) echo mount; break ;;
```

Or add a "Quit" choice

Comment: what can I do if I want to reprint the menu also an valid choices

Comment: Put the select statement in a `while true` loop, and add a `break` after `esac`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use quote, you have to use backtick `` ` `` or `$()` for the commands.

`'ps -A'` should be `ps -A` or `$(ps -a)`.

Answer (score 0):

not too long ago some team mate who is not a lot of experienced in Unix asked me to give him an example of a Bash menu. So I sent him this. Hope it helps you. You dont need to loop if you chain the functions recursively.

```
function Main_Menu() {
    clear
    echo "Select an option ..."
    printf "\n"
    echo "1 - Check CPU"
    echo "2 - Check disk utilization"
    echo "3 - About"
    echo "4 - Exit"

    read -n 1 user_input    
    if [[ "$user_input" == "1" ]]
    then
        Check_CPU
    elif [[ "$user_input" == "2" ]]
    then
        Check_disk_utilization
    elif [[ "$user_input" == "3" ]]
    then
        About
    elif [[ "$user_input" == "4" ]]
    then
        clear
        echo "Chau!!"
    else
        Main_Menu
    fi
}
function Check_CPU(){
    clear

    cpu_values=$( top -b -n2 -p 1  )

    echo "****************************"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "**Current CPU values*"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "$cpu_values"
    echo "****************************"

    echo "Press ESC to go back or any other key to update..."
    printf "\n"

    read -n 1 user_input    
    if [[ "$user_input" == $'\e' ]]
    then
        Main_Menu

    else
        Check_CPU
    fi

}
function Check_disk_utilization(){
    clear

    disk_utilization=$( df -h  )

    echo "****************************"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "**Current Disk Utilization*"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "****************************"
    echo "$disk_utilization"
    echo "****************************"

    echo "Press ESC to go back or any other key to update..."
    printf "\n"

    read -n 1 user_input    
    if [[ "$user_input" == $'\e' ]]
    then
        Main_Menu

    else
        Check_disk_utilization
    fi

}
function About(){
    clear

    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    printf "\n"
    echo "This script was written by XXXXX"
    echo "2017, Montevideo"
    printf "\n"
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Press ESC to go back..."
    printf "\n"

    read -n 1 user_input    
    if [[ "$user_input" == $'\e' ]]
    then
        Main_Menu

    else
        About
    fi

}

Main_Menu
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution before your first edit

In `bash` commands are case-sensitive. There is an `echo` command, but no `Echo` or `ECHO` command. Same goes for `if` and so on.

Simply replace all `ECHO` with `echo`, `IF` with `if`, and `ELIF` with `elif`.

## Solution after your first edit

The `while [ {selection} ]` looks odd. As a simple test, remove it (including the `do` and `done`) without replacement.

## Solution for (probably) upcoming edits

- `echo df -h` does *not* run the `df -h` command, but only prints the literal string `df -h`. Just write `df -h` without the `echo` to run it.
- The `while`-loop should include the `read` command, so that a user can make a new selection, if the previous selection was not valid. Move the `read` command inside the loop and adjust the loop condition. With the current structure, `while true` would be ok.